# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ERROR

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I've been at this problem for 2 weeks now, and I've come across several solutions on Stackoverflow, and other forums, but I am still unable to find a right answer.

I have 3 Tables in my Database: `Users`, `UserGroups`, and `Groups`.

The `Users` have a `one-to-many` relationship with `UserGroups`, and `UserGroups` 
`many-to-one` with `Users`.

The relationship with `Groups` and `UserGroups` is the same as `Users`.

I am using JSF + HIBERNATE + PrimeFaces to construct my application. So I have 3 Data tables in my view - 1 displays the list of users in my database, the other displays the list of groups, and lastly the UserGroup data table displays the list of users and groups.

so this error

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails

APPEARS WHEN I select a user and a group, and I click the "Insert" button. The user and the group does not get inserted into the database table.

I do not think its a mapping error because I tried running a test class by manually inserting values into the database, and it works fine. Can anyone help me out with this?

### USER model:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", targetEntity=UsuariosGrupos.class,fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UsuariosGrupos> usuariosgruposList;

    public Usuarios() {
    }


    @XmlTransient
    public List<UsuariosGrupos> getUsuariosgruposList() {
        return usuariosgruposList;
    }

    public void setUsuariosgruposList(List<UsuariosGrupos> usuariosgruposList) {
        this.usuariosgruposList = usuariosgruposList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idUsuario != null ? idUsuario.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Usuarios)) {
            return false;
        }
        Usuarios other = (Usuarios) object;
        if ((this.idUsuario == null && other.idUsuario != null) || (this.idUsuario != null && !this.idUsuario.equals(other.idUsuario))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "br.model.Usuarios[ idUsuario=" + idUsuario + " ]";
    }

}
```

### UserGroups Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios_grupos")
public class UsuariosGrupos {

    private Integer id_usuario;
    private Integer id_grupo;

    private Usuarios user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_usuario", insertable=false, updatable=false)
       public Usuarios getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Usuarios user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId_grupo() {
        return id_grupo;
    }

    public void setId_grupo(Integer id_grupo) {
        this.id_grupo = id_grupo;
    }

    public Integer getId_usuario() {
        return id_usuario;
    }

    public void setId_usuario(Integer id_usuario) {
        this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
    }
}
```

### Groups model:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="grupos")

    public class Grupos {
        private long id_grupo;
        private String descricao;

        private List<UsuariosGrupos> usergroup;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", targetEntity = UsuariosGrupos.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<UsuariosGrupos> getUsergroup() {
            return usergroup;
        }

        public void setUsergroup(List<UsuariosGrupos> usergroup) {
            this.usergroup = usergroup;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public String getDescricao() {
            return descricao;
        }

        public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public long getId_grupo() {
            return id_grupo;
        }

        public void setId_grupo(long id_grupo) {
            this.id_grupo = id_grupo;
        }    
    }
    `

    Index.xhtml (view) :

          <h:commandButton value="Incluir" actionListener="#{usuariosGruposBean.finishAddUsuariosGrupos}">
                            <f:param name="#{usergroups}" value="#{usergroups}"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
```

### My UserGroups Bean:

```
   @ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UsuariosGruposBean {

    private Usuarios user;
    private UsuariosGrupos userGroups = new UsuariosGrupos();
    private UsuariosGruposDAO userDAO = new UsuariosGruposDAO();
    private UsuariosGruposDAO grpDAO = new UsuariosGruposDAO();
    private UsuariosGruposDAO userGrpDAO = new UsuariosGruposDAO();
    private List<Usuarios> listOfUsuarios;

    private List<UsuariosGrupos> listOfUserGroups;

    public List<Usuarios> getListOfUsuarios() {
        List<Usuarios> usuariosList = userDAO.retrieveUsuarios();
        listOfUsuarios = usuariosList;
        return listOfUsuarios;
    }



    public List<UsuariosGrupos> getListofUserGroups() {
        List<UsuariosGrupos> userGrpList = userGrpDAO.retrieveUsuariosGrupos();
        listOfUserGroups = userGrpList;
        return listOfUserGroups;
    }




    public Usuarios getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Usuarios user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public UsuariosGrupos getUserGroups() {
        return userGroups;
    }

    public void setUserGroups(UsuariosGrupos userGroups) {
        this.userGroups = userGroups;
    }


    public void finishAddUsuariosGrupos() {
        userGroups.setId_usuario(62);
        userGroups.setId_grupo(2);
        userGrpDAO.saveUsuariosGrupos(userGroups);
        listOfUserGroups = null;
    }



}




    This is the error stack that I face when I attempt to add a user and a group to usergroups:
```

> Out 21, 2011 10:15:26 AM
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
>           INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
>           Out 21, 2011 10:15:33 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions WARNING: SQL
>   Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000 Out 21, 2011 10:15:33 AM
>   `org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions SEVERE: Cannot
>   add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`social`.`usuarios_grupos`, CONSTRAINT`fk_usuarios`FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES`usuarios`(`id_usuario`) ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) Out 21, 2011 10:15:33 AM`
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener
>   performExecutions SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with
>   session org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could
>   not execute JDBC batch update     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails (`social`.`usuarios_grupos`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_usuarios` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios`
>   (`id_usuario`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: We are facing same issue any solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

See the underlying generated query by `show_sql=true`,

The problem is you are trying to insert/update a reference which isn't exist.

Comment: humm okay. I think there's something wrong with my usergroups model, I manually inserted data into the database table. However, when I tried retrieving the list to be displayed on my view, it doesn't do so. Maybe there's the root of the problem. Do you have any idea why this is so? even though the mapping is correct, and I am able to insert data into the usergroup table?

Comment: Building on this , is it even possible to retrieve a list of a join table?